# MySQL error while trying to create tables

Tags: php, mysql

Ok I'm trying to find a good working cydia repo download counter and my friend gave me one he uses for his reposms that he created but when I try running the sql I run across this error.

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '"' at line 10

Here is what is in the mysql file:

```
CREATE TABLE `download` (
            `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            `dldate` DATETIME,
            `stats` int(11) NOT NULL,
            `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
            `device` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
            `firmware` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
            `agent` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
            PRIMARY KEY  (`filename`)
            ) ENGINE = MYISAM";
```

Also I'd like to know how I can display the download information from a file on my php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `"` right before the end.

```
CREATE TABLE `download` 
(
        `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        `dldate` DATETIME,
        `stats` int(11) NOT NULL,
        `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
        `device` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
        `firmware` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
        `agent` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
        PRIMARY KEY  (`filename`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;
                 ^------here
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d4dd/1)

Comment: How would I display data from this `stats` int(11) NOT NULL, in my php?

Comment: I have this but I'm not sure if it's correct?   <?PHP
 $sql="SELECT filename, stats, dldate FROM download WHERE filename = 'technologxsetup.deb' "
 echo  $daten['stats']
 ?>

Comment: I am no PHP expert. Ask another question if you are stuck.